# Admin Panel System Design using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, subdomain, system, admin

I'm trying to make an admin panel for a website that is already running. I've never deployed an admin panel feature, so I want to ask you what the best and most common approach to creating one, and what I need to look out for when I launch it using a subdomain admin.mydomain.com. This website already has users and sessions controller, and I also would like to know how to differentiate two different authentication systems.

Thanks!

Comment: Try these gems: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces

Answer (score 0):

you can use Active admin gem.
see the complete documentation from this link https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html